# Changing the colour of ol.geom.LineString in open layers 3

Tags: javascript, android, openlayers-3

I am trying to write some javascript in my android app which will draw a line from one point to another based on the values passed in via a PolyLineOptions object from android.

I have wrote a couple of JSInterfaces to get the relevant info from the PolyLineOptions object such as latlng and colour and I can get it to draw the line fine, however when I try to change the colour of it, it doesn't do anything, ive even tried changing the width, and still nothing.

NOTE: I have wrote the colour value to the log and it is coming through correctly so all the JSInterface stuff is working as expected.

```
function drawPolyLine(polyLine){

if(polyLine != null){

    var list = window.JSInterface.getPointsFromPolyLine(polyLine)

    var count = window.JSInterface.getLengthFromLatLngList(list)

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i+=2)
    {
        var lat1 = window.JSInterface.getLatFromLatLngList(list, i);
        var lng1 = window.JSInterface.getLngFromLatLngList(list, i);
        var lat2 = window.JSInterface.getLatFromLatLngList(list, i+1);
        var lng2 = window.JSInterface.getLngFromLatLngList(list, i+1);

        var coordinates = [[lng1,lat1],[lng2,lat2]];

        var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
        lineString.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

        var color = window.JSInterface.getColorFromPolyLine(polyLine);

      var styles = [
        // linestring
        new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 2
          })
        })
      ];

        var line = new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: lineString,
                    name: 'Line',
                    style: styles
                });
        linesSource.addFeature(line);

    }
}
```

}

Would anyone be able to help me figure out what I am doing wrong? It seems to be completely ignoring the style. I am guessing its something silly but I just can't see it.

Comment: You haven't used the color returned from window.JSInterface.getColorFromPolyLine(polyLine) in your style. You have set color: '#ffcc33'. So '#ffcc33' will be the color of your line.

Comment: sorry that was just some code I had copied from somewhere else and forgot to change it. It wasn't that, it was ignoring the style completely. It turns out that if you use line.setStyle(styles) then it works. but by setting it in the creation of the feature doesn't. I don't know why

Answer (score 3):

I Have figured it out. It turns out that you aren't allowed to set the style when you create the feature you need to use:

```
            var line = new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: lineString,
                    name: 'Line',
                    //style: styles
                });

                line.setStyle(styles);
```

I don't understand why, so if someone could explain then feel free to answer and I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: `style` cannot be set on `ol.Feature` constructor. Same with `id`, you should use `feature.setId('foo')`. Certainly, core developers have their reason for this.